# SQL | insert into + select + variables with condition?

Tags: mysql, variables, select, insert, conditional-statements

My task is inserting 3 random datas per ID from another table
 
and I got a mistake with syntax

```
set @num := 0, @type := '' ,@stat :='';
INSERT INTO random 
as 
(
SELECT
*
FROM (
select userID,userNAME, chaID, chaNAME,goal,gender,
      @num := if(@type = userID, @num +1,1) as row_number,
      @type := userID as dummy,
      @stat as status
  from userchar
  order by userID
) as x where x.row_number <= 3)
```

I'm going to put this code in event scheduler to insert the new datas in daily

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO random as ( SELECT * FROM ( select userID,userNAME,
>   chaID, c' at line 2

thank you so much for every suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is trying to run multiple statements at the same time.  You can fix this by initializing the variables in the query itself:

```
INSERT INTO random( . . . )
    select u.*
    from (select userID, userNAME, chaID, chaNAME, goal, gender,
                 (@num := if(@u = userID, @num +1,
                            if(@u := userId, 1, 1)
                           )
                ) as row_number,
                userID as dummy,
                @stat as status
           from userchar u cross join
                (select @u = '', @num := 0, @stat := '') params
           order by userID, rand()
          ) u
    where u.row_number <= 3;
```

There are several other issues:

- When using `insert`, always list the columns.  This is particularly important if you are learning SQL, so you learn good habits.
- You should not assign a variable value in one expression and use it in another.  MySQL (and MariaDB) do not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select`, so the expressions can be evaluated in either order.
- If you want *random* rows, then use `rand()`.  There is a difference between "indeterminate" and "random".

Comment: it's working fine now. thank you so much for your solve and suggestions >_< I'll learn more and more !